How do I let clients on different networks communicate?
Background : I have implemented a client-server architecture based messaging application that lets users on the same LAN communicate with each other on a one-to-one basis. I did this by defining IP as LOCAL in all cases of the client instance. It uses port 8080 on my server.
A few lines from my code :
#define PORT 8080
#define MAX_SIZE 1024
#define IP_ADDRESS "local"

Now, out of curiosity I want to extend this concept to clients on different networks communicating with each other (via my server for now). I know this would require some kind of DNS resolution. I  have also read up about the getaddrinfo() method and understood (I may be wrong) that it would help me with my task.  Could anyone help me out with the details?
I have not tried programming anything , I just looked into the man pages and Beej's guide for getaddrinfo() as of now because I could not understand the above mentioned function itself completely and what it returns and also have not looked for alternate methods.

You probably won't be able to talk directly to machines on another network due to firewalls and NAT

Yeah practically true , but in theory how would you implement such a functionality, I am just experimenting around , nothing production worthy

While getaddrinfo is certainly a way to resolve hostnames and generally turn strings into IP-adresses, it's not required for anything. At the core, you need the IP address of the host you want to talk to; how you get that doesn't really matter.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)

At which address do you intend to host your server on anyway? From your home address you likely won't get provided with a fix URL anyway (unless you request explicitly at your ISP – against money most likely…). In that case some dynamic DNS service might help you out.

Do you expect us to write a guide to getaddrinfo() for you, just like Beej's but better? That would be a rather difficult task.

The guide appears pretty clear to me – it might help to describe what exactly you did not understand…

no no i did not expect a guide , i just wanted a method that I could proceed with , because I did not really understand how tto go forward with just getaddrinfo()

@Aconcagua I thought about using a proxy server. I could route my server requests and replies through the proxy and then the client could also communicate with the proxy.would that work?

You mean a proxy server on every machine you have a client on? So you'd 'outsource' address resolution to that proxy? If you had a single proxy all clients would connect to then at client side you have exactly the same problem as without: Where do you get the IP address from? Unless that proxy has a well-known public IP, that is...

@Aconcagua what if my proxy server could get a global IP (I cant of course but if i could get a global IP then it could work right?) , I am looking into hole punching for now ,it was recommended by some user above.

Global IP is not all about. If you have access to the internet provider via an ISP the router you usually connect to already gets a global address. But that address can change over time, potentially even with every time you (re-) connect – if you want to rely on IP addresses you need a fix global address (or your clients would all have to call you by phone to ask you for the current IP address…). But if you indeed have such a static IP address – whether proxy or not – then the clients can simply connect directly to that address.

@Aconcagua ahh I think now I get it lol , What about a linux VM on cloud running nginx?

@zero_day Then a step back. If you have a server, being VM or not, that is reachable from the internet directly – then why use it as a (reverse) proxy at all? Why not run your server application directly there? This would relieve you from having to run your own hardware. In that case nginx would only be necessary if your own service is a web application (written e.g. in PHP). But such a virtual server usually costs money (at least I'm not aware of a free service).

And the IP is not guaranteed to be fix over all ages. You might switch the service provider or it gets assigned another IP by IANA's national agent (-> configurable at client!). I personally would go another way: Rewrite your server as web application (e.g. in PHP); getting the IP address of other clients would then be implemented as AJAX requests (and if part of your application getting a list of all connected clients as well). Then learn how getaddrinfo actually works to resolve the web server's address. You might even find a free web hosting service - consult your favourite search engine…

Benefits then are that you don't have to pay at all or at least have to pay much less and still don't have to run your own hardware at home. If you don't consider this an option then I'd make your own server publicly available via a dynamic DNS provider (there are quite a few out there – just make sure you have one robust against NAT coming from your router/ISP) and – guess – again learn how getaddrinfo works.

@Aconcagua allright cool , thanks a lot! will probably rewrite it as a web server
